# array deccleration

Tags: arrays

I have written a code in php to connect and insert into a MSSQL database. i don't know much in php because am new to this. i used odbc to connect database.user can enter his details through the form. after submitting the form the details are getting stored into a database.
 while inserting rows into a database am not trying to insert duplicate values . for this i have given if conditions.these conditions are able to notice the user  cname and name exist in the database if the same name exist. but the else part after these conditions not working i.e rows are not getting inserted. i put everything inside the while loop. how can i correct it?

this is my code written in php

```
    $connect = odbc_connect('ServerDB','sa', 'pwd');//connects database

       $query2="select count(*) from company";//this is needer for loop through
        $result2=odbc_exec($connect,$query2);
        while(odbc_fetch_row($result2));
       {
         $count=odbc_result($result2,1);
       echo "</br>","$count";
      }

      $query1="select * from company";
    $result1 = odbc_exec($connect, $query1);

     # fetch the data from the database
   $index=0;

   while(odbc_fetch_row($result1))
      {
      $compar[$count] = odbc_result($result1, 1);
     $namearray[$count] = odbc_result($result1, 2);

         if($compar[$count]==$_POST['cname'])
    {
    echo "<script> alert(\"cname Exists\") </script>";
         }

        else   if($namearray[$count]==$_POST['name'])
    {
        echo "<script> alert(\"Name Exists\") </script>";
    }
     else {

      $query=("INSERT INTO company(cname,name) VALUES ('$_POST[cname]','$_POST[name]') ");
   $result = odbc_exec($connect, $query);
    echo "<script> alert(\"Row Inserted\") </script>";
   } }
```

Comment: You can't declare an array to be of a certain length in PHP. That's one of it's dynamic characteristics.

Comment: then can directly assign  $compar[$count] = odbc_result($result1, 1); like this?

Comment: I don't work with ODBC, but I would recommend the [MSSQL parts of the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php), and looking into the [MSSQL PDO Server Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php). I think what you're saying, though, is correct, in that you just set the rows returned to an array variable dynamically.

Comment: For instance, a construct like this is typically how databases are queried in PHP using the vendor-specific functions (as opposed to the PDO library, which is more abstract): http://codepad.org/jZZlddlr

Answer (score 1):

You generally don't allocate memory in PHP.  The PHP interpreter handles it for you. Just go ahead and assign elements to your array and all the memory allocation is taken care of for you.

Comment: but when assign elements to array count holds the last value which entered , comparision happens  only with last row not with all. how do i compare with all rows?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to look into `in_array()`.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 0):

$index = 0;

Then you do $index++ until the last index is reached.

So index further on stays e.g. 12

So anywhere you can only access the index [12]

Answer (score 0):

In PHP arrays are implemented as what would be a HashMap in Java. It will be sized automatically depending on what you put into it, and there is no way you can give an initial capacity.